# the source list for content security policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source in safari angular 5

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, recaptcha, google-api-js-client

I have implemented google-recapthca in angular 5 and it working well for all browers but in safari i got following error:

### the source list for content security policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: "strict-dynamic". It will be ignored.

my safari version is : 12.0

my html code

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="gAuth" data-sitekey="your_site_key_here"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Adblock on? I've seen the error before and it seems like AdBlock can cause this error.

Optionally you can check this thread out: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/397

Seems like the issue can be caused by multiple things.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that issue. I'm on Safari 13.1 on MacOs 10.15.4. No addblockers installed.
Is Recaptcha even using this client? It does not figure in the listing of the README.

Even on the Google Recaptcha demo page, the error is present. [Google Recaptcha demo](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo)

But let me make you aware this error doesn't break captcha from working. The captcha works as usual on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Adblock try pausing and restarting (yup, standard old process). Worked for me when Youtube was completely broken.